# forbid cgi invocation by direct url, but allow via a RewriteRule

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache-2.4

I want to allow anonymous client execute a script via a special URL, but not directly. Everything else should require auth.

```
<Directory "/srv/http">
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory "/srv/http/html">
    RewriteRule ^hello/dostuff/(.*)$ /cgi-bin/hello.sh?anon=1&x=$1 [B]
</Directory>

# require auth for everything with one exception below
<Location />
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName intranet
    AuthUserFile "conf/passwd"
    Require user test
</Location>

# allow anonymous access inside /hello/
<Location /hello/>
    Require all granted
</Location>
```

`/hello/foobar` gives me 404 as expected, but `/hello/dostuff/foobar` asks for password. It seems the `<Location />` check is performed twice: before and after rewriting:

access_log:

```
192.168.65.1 - - [22/Oct/2015:12:49:04 +0300] "GET /hello/dostuff/foobar HTTP/1.1" 401 381
```

error_log:

```
[Thu Oct 22 12:49:04 2015] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted URI:/hello/dostuff/foobar
[Thu Oct 22 12:49:04 2015] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted URI:/hello/dostuff/foobar
[Thu Oct 22 12:49:04 2015] AH01626: authorization result of Require user test: denied (no authenticated user yet) URI:/cgi-bin/hello.sh
[Thu Oct 22 12:49:04 2015] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: denied (no authenticated user yet) URI:/cgi-bin/hello.sh
```

Full conf:

```
ServerRoot "/etc/httpd"
Listen 80
LoadModule cgi_module modules/mod_cgi.so
LoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.so
LoadModule unixd_module modules/mod_unixd.so
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so

LoadModule authn_file_module modules/mod_authn_file.so
LoadModule authn_core_module modules/mod_authn_core.so
LoadModule authz_user_module modules/mod_authz_user.so
LoadModule authz_core_module modules/mod_authz_core.so
LoadModule access_compat_module modules/mod_access_compat.so
LoadModule auth_basic_module modules/mod_auth_basic.so
LoadModule reqtimeout_module modules/mod_reqtimeout.so
LoadModule include_module modules/mod_include.so
LoadModule filter_module modules/mod_filter.so
LoadModule mime_module modules/mod_mime.so
LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so
LoadModule env_module modules/mod_env.so
LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
LoadModule setenvif_module modules/mod_setenvif.so
LoadModule version_module modules/mod_version.so
LoadModule mpm_event_module modules/mod_mpm_event.so

User http
Group http

DocumentRoot "/srv/http/html"

RewriteEngine On

<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory "/srv/http">
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory "/srv/http/html">
    RewriteRule ^hello/dostuff/(.*)$ /cgi-bin/hello.sh?anon=1&x=$1 [B]
</Directory>

<Files ".ht*">
    Require all denied
</Files>
<IfModule log_config_module>
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common
    <IfModule logio_module>
      LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
    </IfModule>
    CustomLog "/var/log/httpd/access_log" common
</IfModule>

SetEnvIf Request_URI "(^.*$)" RURI=$1

ErrorLog "/var/log/httpd/error_log"
LogLevel debug
#ErrorLogFormat "[%t] [%l] [pid %P] %F: %E: [client %a] %M URI:%{RURI}e"
ErrorLogFormat "[%t] %M URI:%{RURI}e"

<IfModule alias_module>
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/srv/http/cgi-bin/"
</IfModule>
<Directory "/srv/http/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
<IfModule mime_module>
    TypesConfig conf/mime.types
    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz
</IfModule>

# require auth for everything with one exception below
<Location />
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName intranet
    AuthUserFile "conf/passwd"
    Require user test
</Location>

# allow anonymous access inside /hello/
<Location /hello/>
    Require all granted
</Location>
```

Answer (score 0):

Enable `LogLevel debug` for your httpd. In the resulting log entries you may find ie. that using old syntax access rules (like `Allow from ...`, `Satisfy ...`) gives unexpected results, especially when mixed with new style (`<RequireAny>`, `<RequireAll>`, etc.). Using httpd 2.4 you should go with the new syntax only to avoid this kind of problems.

Other than that, I believe you want to match `^/hello/dostuff/...` - pay attention to the leading slash that is missing in your configuration.

Comment: edited question according to your advices

Answer (score 0):

Set a variable `let_me_in` in `RewriteRule` and grant access not only when user authed, but also when this variable is set:

```
<Directory "/srv/http/html">
    RewriteRule ^hello/dostuff/(.*)$ /cgi-bin/hello.sh?anon=1&x=$1 [B,E=let_me_in]
</Directory>

<Location />
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName intranet
    AuthUserFile "conf/passwd"
    Require user test
    Require env REDIRECT_let_me_in
</Location>
```